# Do you catch expected exceptions in the controller or business service of your asp.net mvc application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, exception

I am developing an asp.net mvc application where user1 could delete data records which were just loaded before by user2. User2 either changes this non-existent data record (Update) or is doing an insert with this data in another table that a foreign-key constraint is violated.

Where do you catch such expected exceptions?

In the Controller of your asp.net mvc application or in the business service?

*Just a sidenote: I only catch the SqlException here if its a ForeignKey constraint exception to tell the user that another user has deleted a certain parent record and therefore he can not create the testplan. But this code is not fully implemented yet!*

**Controller**:

```
  public JsonResult CreateTestplan(Testplan testplan)
  {
   bool success = false;
   string error = string.Empty;

   try
  {
   success = testplanService.CreateTestplan(testplan);
   }
  catch (SqlException ex)
   {
   error = ex.Message;
   }
   return Json(new { success = success, error = error }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
  }
```

**OR**

**Business service:**

```
public Result CreateTestplan(Testplan testplan)
        {
            Result result = new Result();
            try
            {
                using (var con = new SqlConnection(_connectionString))
                using (var trans = new TransactionScope())
                {
                    con.Open();

                    _testplanDataProvider.AddTestplan(testplan);
                    _testplanDataProvider.CreateTeststepsForTestplan(testplan.Id, testplan.TemplateId);
                    trans.Complete();
                    result.Success = true;
                }
            }
            catch (SqlException e)
            {
                result.Error = e.Message;
            }
            return result;
        }
```

**then in the Controller:**

```
public JsonResult CreateTestplan(Testplan testplan)
      {
       Result result = testplanService.CreateTestplan(testplan);      
       return Json(new { success = result.success, error = result.error }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
      }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Foreign key constraint violation should be checked and displayed properly. You can easily check if rows in related table exist and show proper message. The same can be done with row updates. Servers return number of rows affected, so you know what happens.

Even if you don't make these checks, you should catch SQL exceptions. For average application user, message about constraint violation means nothing. This message is for developer and you should log it with ELMAH or Log4Net library. User should see message similar to "We are sorry. This row has been probably modified by another user and your operation has become invalid." and in case he asks developer about it, developer should check logs and see the cause.

**EDIT**

I believe you should check errors in service. Controller should not be aware of data access layer. For controller, it doesn't matter if you store data in SQL database or in files. Files can throw file access exception, SQL has other ones. Controller shouldn't worry about it. You can catch data access layer exceptions in service and throw exception with type dedicated for service layer. Controller can catch it and display proper message. So the answer is:

```
public class BusinessService 
{
    public Result CreateTestplan(Testplan testplan)
    {
        Result result = new Result();
        try
        {
            using (var con = new SqlConnection(_connectionString))
            using (var trans = new TransactionScope())
            {
                con.Open();

                _testplanDataProvider.AddTestplan(testplan);
                _testplanDataProvider.CreateTeststepsForTestplan(testplan.Id, testplan.TemplateId);
                trans.Complete();
                result.Success = true;
            }
        }
        catch (SqlException e)
        {
            ....log in ELMAH or Log4Net using other logging framework...
            throw new ServiceException("We are sorry. Your operation conflicted with another operation in database. It has been cancelled.");
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: What you said is helpfull, but I still miss where you say why I should catch the exception in the controller or service.

Comment: 1.) "Controller can catch it..." But then my result class is obsolete. I have then the error in my controller  and the true/false can be determined wether an exception happens or not. Afair sometimes i even have to check the innerexception message. 2.) I would rather catch 2 custom exception types in the service which could come from 2 different dataprovider methods. What do you think?

Comment: 3.) "throw new ServiceException("We are sorry. Your operation conflicted with another operation in database. It has been cancelled.");" Would it not be good to get the Exception code number here? For example get the code for concurreny/fk constraint violation /duplicate insert so I can show the user a much more detailed error message instead of saying:"your operation conflicted bla bla" ??

Comment: @Pascal: 1) Yes, your Result class is obsolete. Maybe sometimes you have to check inner exception, but this is you, not regular user. Regular user won't understand inner exception. You should log it somewhere else, not show it to user. 2) I don't understand. 3) You can show number, but why? You don't want users to call you with foreign key constraint. It happens and user have to understand it, not investingate. For unusual errors, real errors, you have application logs and you should monitor them.

Comment: 1.) agree 2.) Forget it, your advice is fine I think. 3.)Did not want to show the number to the user its just for me personally,that the BLL knows with the Number what Custom exception to throw when he catches the DAL-SqlException. Thanks for all.